# Unity - Animated property doesn't reach end value?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a game using the `Unity` game engine. I wanted to animate my UI `alpha` with a canvas group and the animator. The animation clip simply animates the alpha property from `0` to `1` in one second. When I tested it, it looked like it's working in the game, but when I inspected my object, I saw that the value of the alpha property is `0.9999998`. It's unnoticeable in game but it's very annoying for me. The keyframe in the Animation window clearly says `1` after one second, but at the end of the animation the value isn't exactly one.

Just to give more details, after the alpha animation, the animator transitions to an empty animation which does nothing. The transition has exit time set to `1`, duration and offset set to `0`. So, it's supposed to wait for the alpha animation to finish.

Is there a reason that the value of alpha doesn't reach exactly 1, and is there a way to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Animators have their own `Update` method.  Between FixUpdate, LateUpdate, Update and other methods, they all need to be time-sliced.  I believe `0.9999998` is a very respectable granularity.  Don't sweat it.

Comment: Maybe, but I'd expect that when they finish `Update` they'd set the values to the last keyframe. I really hate seeing this number that is just begging to be `1`

Comment: Lol.  Change it in your code or pretend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For practical Unity purposes, 0.9999998 is exactly 1 (due to floating point issues - aka division, etc it doesn't say 1). More info about that:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

**Here is how you handle float comparisons in Unity:**

```
Mathf.Approximately()
```

**Documentation:** https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html

> Floating point imprecision makes comparing floats using the equals
>   operator inaccurate.

**Example C# code you can try to see how this works:**

```
float f1 = 0.9999998f;
float f2 = 1;

Debug.Log($"f1: {f1}, f2: {f2}, f1 == f2: {f1 == f2}, Mathf.Approximately(f1,f2): {Mathf.Approximately(f1, f2)}");
```

**As you can see, the out put is:**

> f1: 0.9999998, f2: 1, f1 == f2: False, Mathf.Approximately(f1,f2):
>   ***True***

If you need to display the value, then format / round it, etc.